# Shift column names one to the left in R

Tags: r, dataframe, shift, names

I have been trying now since a while to do this:

I want to move the headings of a excel sheet one column up in R:

Example:

Before:

```
NO  Id  AGE  Gender
XY  24  F
fg  67  M
```

After:

```
Id  Age  Gender
XY  24   F
fg  67   M
```

It is a big Table with 58.000 rows and 500 columns. So it needs to be somehow without naming each individual column.

Thank you :)

Comment: Your "After" has once less column name. What's the new name for the final column?

Comment: The first column name will be replaced by the one coming from the right side.

Comment: The "Before" data frame is not well-defined - it has 4 column names but only 3 values in row 1 and 2 - so where are the values for column NO?

Comment: Please read the posting instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag.  In particular, if `DF` is your input data frame then edit the question to show the output of `dput(head(DF))` so that it is reproducible.

Comment: Please see details in answer from Hamza. Thats exactly want I mean, only difference I want to shift to the left. Thank you

Comment: Please see edited post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column name `NO` should be deleted, you could use

```
names(data)[1:(ncol(data)-1)] <- names(data)[2:ncol(data)]
data[, ncol(data)] <- NULL
```

You first shift the column names to the left by one position, and then delete the last column of your dataframe `data`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice one :)

```
x=data.table(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)
#> x
#   a b c d
#1: 1 2 3 4

names(x)[1:(ncol(x)-1)] = names(x)[2:(ncol(x))]
#> x
#   b c d d <-- the last colname gets duplicated of course
#1: 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: that looks good. but not sure what i am doing wrong the whole program runs once i run this row. How can i just rename the table like this without running the rest of the program?

Answer (score 0):

Data :

```
data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~NO, ~Id, ~Age, ~Gender, ~month, ~year,
  "XY", 24, "F", NA, 1990, NA,
  "fg", 67, "M", NA, 1991, NA,
  "dZ", 32, "M", NA, 1992, NA
)
data
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  NO       Id Age   Gender month year 
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <lgl>  <dbl> <lgl>
1 XY       24 F     NA      1990 NA   
2 fg       67 M     NA      1991 NA   
3 dZ       32 M     NA      1992 NA 

names(data) <- names(data)[2:ncol(data)]
data <- data[head(seq_len(ncol(data)), -1)]
data

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Id      Age Gender month  year
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <lgl> <dbl>
1 XY       24 F      NA     1990
2 fg       67 M      NA     1991
3 dZ       32 M      NA     1992
```

#### Or, if the last column is empty, you can do like this :

```
data[] <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(data)), data[head(seq_along(data), -1)])
data$NO <- NULL
data
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Id      Age Gender month  year
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <lgl> <dbl>
1 XY       24 F      NA     1990
2 fg       67 M      NA     1991
3 dZ       32 M      NA     1992
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to shift to the left, how do I do that? So NO will be replaced by Id, Id by Age, Age by Gender and so on. NO will disappear completly.

Comment: Thank you. Do I understand correctly that this would delete the first column? I just want to move the first row one to the left

Comment: Thank you but how it looks for me now is: I get an additional column between Id and Age, the first row is not shifted to the left

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the first element of your column names:

```
names(x) = names(x)[-1]
```